# Apache Archiva Maven

Tags: apache, maven, archiva

Not able to download artifacts from central maven repository.

```xml
<mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
    <mirror>
        <id>internal</id>
        <name>Proxy Cache - Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/archiva/repository/internal</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>

  </mirrors>
```

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to do? What changes did you do recently? Add more information to get a response

Comment: Could be a problem with archiva configuration. Could you also follow the configuration as described in archiva [documentation](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M2/userguide/using-repository.html)?

Comment: what kind of problems do you have ?
Any logs to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add information, like error log, and what you really need !

As a beggining, does you archiva repository needs credentials. If true, consider adding them like this :

```xml
  <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
  <servers>
        <server>
            <id>internal</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
  </servers>
```